# Loop through images in JQuery

Tags: jquery, html, image, loops

I have 9 images on a page .This is html code.

```
<div id="img-grp-wrap">
    <div class="img-wrap">
        <img src="1.jpg"  alt="aa" />
        <img src="2.jpg" alt="hh" />
        <img src="3.jpg" alt="bb" />
        <img src="4.jpg" alt="cc" />
        <img src="5.jpg"  alt="aa" />
        <img src="6.jpg" alt="hh" />
        <img src="8.jpg" alt="cc" />
        <img src="9.jpg"  alt="aa" />
        <img src="10.jpg" alt="hh" />
    </div>   

    <div class="next_button">
       <img src="http://annhowardesign.com/images/arrowright.jpg" class="next" alt="Next"/>
    </div>
    <div class="previous_button">
       <img src="http://annhowardesign.com/images/arrowleft.jpg" class="prev" alt="Previous"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

The next and previous button actually are the images. i need to loop through all images so that when the page loads ,the previous link image should be invisible and after click on the next it will be visible.Similarly at last image,the next link will be invisible.
   How can i do it in JQuery?
   Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Have you heard about Lightbox..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i promissed i made for you a jQuery plugin, try it.
It will work just like this:

call on document ready: `$( '.img-wrap' ).imgSlider({ next: '.next_button', prev: 'previous_button' });` or you can edit it in the code where plugin extending options.

**next** and **prev** option is to define yours navigation buttons. Enjoy. ;)

Result you can test here: http://jsfiddle.net/GomatoX/GKkRM/

```js
    (function($){

        $.fn.imgSlider = function( options ){

            o = $.extend({
                next: '#next_button',
                prev: '#previous_button'
            }, options);

            var thisCallback = this;

            $( this ).find( 'img' ).each(function(){

                $( this ).hide();
            });
            $( this ).find( 'img' ).first().addClass( 'active' ).show();
            $( o.prev ).hide();

            // binding event next
            $( o.next ).bind( 'click' ,function(){

                var nextImg = $( thisCallback ).find( '.active' ).next();
                if ( nextImg.length == 0 ) {

                    return false;
                }
                $( o.prev ).show();
                $( thisCallback ).find( 'img' ).removeClass( 'active' ).hide();
                nextImg.addClass( 'active' ).show();
                if ( nextImg.next().length == 0 ) {

                    $( this ).hide();
                }
            });
            // binding event prev
            $( o.prev ).bind( 'click' ,function(){

                var prevImg = $( thisCallback ).find( '.active' ).prev();
                if ( prevImg.length == 0 ) {

                    return false;
                }
                $( o.next ).show();
                $( thisCallback ).find( 'img' ).removeClass( 'active' ).hide();
                prevImg.addClass( 'active' ).show();
                if ( prevImg.prev().length == 0 ) {

                    $( this ).hide();
                }
            });
        }
    })(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 1):

I would add ids to all images from 'image1' to 'image10'. Then I would add a class to the active image and do a check if image with id of 1 have that class. So try something like this:

```
var no = $(".img-wrap > img").length;
//check if the first image is active           
if($("#image1").hasClass("active")){
             $("#prev").hide();
//check if the last image is active
        }else if($("#image"+no).hasClass("active")){
    $("#next").hide();
    }
```